Linear interpolation function `interp1d`, replacement after deprecation
In SciPy, there are numerous interpolation function that return a function, e.g., Akima1DInterpolator. I'd like to have the same for a simple linear interpolator. interp1d does the trick, but is deprecated. What can I replace it with?
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import Akima1DInterpolator, interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


t = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 4)
y = np.array([1.0, 0.8, 0.7, 1.2])

# ak = Akima1DInterpolator(t, y)
# works, but deprecated:
ak = interp1d(t, y, kind="linear")

tt = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 200)
yy = ak(tt)

plt.plot(tt, yy)
plt.plot(t, y, "x")
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()



How about just numpy.interp?

@CoryKramer Doesn't return a function.

According to this table, SciPy recommends np.interp for a 1 dimensional linear problem. This can be converted into a function returning a function like so:
def create_linear_interpolator(t, y):
    def inner(x):
        return np.interp(x, t, y)
    return inner
ak = create_linear_interpolator(t, y)

The ak object can then be called to interpolate any specific x value.
Alternatively, this is a bit of a hack, but a first-order spline is equivalent to linear interpolation.
ak = make_interp_spline(t, y, k=1)


Rigoristically, interp1d is not deprecated, it's declared legacy. There are currently no plans to remove it in any shape or form.
In new code, yes, we recommend what we believe are better alternatives.
